# How to open a set of pages at startup in Selenium Web driver?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to add user profile preference in Chrome Webdriver to set a list of specific websites that should be opened on startup, but I can't make it happen.

I'm using the latest Selenium Chrome Web driver, and I tried numerous approaches to get it working. Chrome instance always open "data;," tab without opening a set of required pages. I found Chrome prefs here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

```
optionOn.AddUserProfilePreference("session.restore_on_startup", 4)

Dim wbs As New List(Of String)(New String() {"https://google.com", "https://google.com", "https://google.com", "https://google.com"})

optionOn.AddUserProfilePreference("session.startup_urls", wbs)
```

I expect to have 4 tabs opened each time a user runs executable. There are no error messages and turns out ChromeDriver ignores User profile preferences that I set.

Comment: You can try parallel test run with any number of browser instances and respective URL's, will that suffice your requirement? or u want all URL's in a single browser instance?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I need a single browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple tabs by sending hot keys to the driver. Control+t or Command+t depending on your machine's OS. However, controlling those tabs is not supported yet and not doable with the current capabilities of the driver and the libraries.

Comment: I don't want to send hotkeys or to use JS to open tabs. I want to use the advantage of settings > On Startup > Open a specific page or set of pages

Answer (score 0):

Add 'first_run_tabs' instead of 'startup_urls'

```
optionOn.AddUserProfilePreference("first_run_tabs", wbs)
```